# Why SSRS renders one cell as a div but other as a table in two different sections of the report?

Tags: performance, service, reporting-services, reporting, rendering

I have problem with reporting services rendering on the client which is performing very slow. I have checked that data retrieval is pretty fast but internet explorer is taking lot of time to render the report.

When I inspect the html emitted by reporting services I find that cells are rendered in two different ways.

1 - Inside a DIV 
2 - Inside a TABLE

I know that DIV outperforms table when rendering. You can observe this behavior when your report has large number of cells.

Could anyone please tell me what can I do in the RDL to make every cell render as a DIV instead of TABLE?

Thanks.

Comment: If you add a "table" object it will render as a table in html.  No way to change that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. The CanGrow property of the cell when set to False causes the cell to render as a TABLE. When this perperty is set to True, the cell is rendered as a DIV. This reduces the size of html rendered by reporting services and internet explorer renders the report faster.

P.S: You can only see the difference when viewing a very large report.